# gulp installation global vs. local as dev dependency

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install

From the instructions page of gulp, it's asked to install it globally as well as in the project as dev dependency.

My question is why do we need to install it twice? Why can't the project one use the global one?

and I do get this error prompting to install it locally and I've followed this tutorial as well but still stuck. http://blog.webbb.be/command-not-found-node-npm/

```
[11:47:51] Local gulp not found in ~/Documents/project
[11:47:51] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Link-> https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means you didn't install `gulp` locally. This means you have to add it to your dependencies in `package.json` (or just call `npm i gulp --save`).

It needs to be installed locally because `gulpfile.js` typically runs some code related to `gulp`. That's why it calls `var gulp = require('gulp');` at the top of your `gulpfile.js`. This call loads `gulp` from your package `node_modules`. That's also where functions like `gulp.task` or `gulp.src` come from.

At the same you want to easily use `gulp` in CLI, that's why it needs to be installed also globally so you can run it by just:

```
$ gulp
```

Btw, you can also run just your local `gulp`:

1. Insert to your `package.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "gulp": "gulp",
   }
   ```

   This tells `npm` that by executing `gulp` command we want to run script `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`.
2. Run (you'd have to do this in all projects):

   ```
   $ npm run gulp
   ```

So it's definitely easier to install it globally.

Comment: Thanks or the comprehensive reply, it's making sense, just to understand more, when you're in a project directory using terminal and then you issue a command `$ gulp` it launches the local one or the global one?

Comment: When you're inside your project it runs the global one. Try running `$ which gulp`. On my system it's for example installed in `/opt/local/bin/gulp`.

Comment: ok, `which gulp` returned `/usr/local/bin/gulp` in my case, however the global one looks for the local one when I issued the command `$ gulp` in a non-project directory

Comment: found these two commands confusing, `npm install gulp-cli -g` and `npm install gulp -g`, what's the difference between these two programs?

Comment: `gulp-cli` is the one that you install globally and is availably by calling just `$ gulp`. You probably don't want to install `npm install gulp -g`. All package dependencies for your project should be installed locally.